# Firefox Developer Edition - unable to view JavaScript file in debugger

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am having trouble getting the new Firefox Developer Edition (Developer Tools) to show loaded source files in the debugger.

I am running a Spring MVC Web app running on Tomcat locally and am able to view the source fine when explicitly putting the path in the browsers address bar. However when trying to debug through javascript files I get a "**Loading...**" indicator and the file never loads:

[image]

Chrome Developer tools seems to be working for debugging and will load the files fine with the same setup.

I am at a loss at what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Download [Firefox Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/). Check if you can reproduce the issue there. If not, wait next build, it should be fixed. Otherwise open an issue on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=__default__&product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a bug in the DevTools. Check if the issue is still present in [Firefox Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly). If it is not present there, it likely already got fixed. Otherwise you should [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=__default__&product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Debugger) and try to include a minimal test case. You may also include any related errors logged to the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (can be opened via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or main menu > *Web Developer* > *Browser Console*) when trying to open the source.